# Meteor onRendered but also when url changes

Tags: meteor

I have a header in my project that can sometimes changes based on a specific url.
I want the header to be reloaded if the path/url has changed. Currently, I do this:

```
Template.Header.onRendered(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("project") > -1) {
     // do something with the header (add for example a <option> element)
    }
});
```

The "do something"-code works, if the url contains project than the code gets executed and I get (for example) an extra option element, however when I change to an url without project than the extra option element should be removed.  How do I need to change the code?

Comment: `ostrio:flow-router-extra` has a reactive helper that watches path changes: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router/blob/master/docs/api/watchPathChange.md

Comment: Are you using a routing library?